# How to create dynamic y scale values in D3 js depending on the screen size?

Tags: angularjs, d3.js

Im creating a line chart graph using d3 js. I need a solution to change the y scale values when I resize the window instead of scroll bar.

I have added the code below which adds scroll bar when I resize the screen size. I want design dynamic y scale values when we resize for different screen sizes.
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { 
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 2;
  fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>

<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<script>

// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

// Set the ranges
var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

// Define the line
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

// Adds the svg canvas
var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

    // Add the valueline path.
    svg.append("path")  
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", valueline(data));

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis
    svg.append("g")     
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(yAxis);

});

</script>
</body>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A method I like to use is to wrap the code in a function (lets call it `main()`), and re-run when the screen size changes.

At the beginning of this new `main()` function, remove the old (and now redundantly sized) svg.

```
d3.select("#<id of svg>").remove();
```

Then, create the new y scale using

```
var new_width = document.getElementById("<Div ID>").clientWidth;
var new_height = document.getElementById("<Div ID>").clientHeight;
```

and apply these to the new svg as you create it. D3 should allow you to run the `.remove()` line before the initial svg has been created. Make sure to then add an id when you create the svg (using `attr("id", "<id of svg>")`).

After that, you can call the main() function on resizing with

```
d3.select(window).on( "resize", main() );
```

The way in which you want to actually size your `Div` will now rely on your CSS, so you can use something like `{height:50vh}` or whatever you like.

Hope this helps.

P.S. By the way, why are you using D3 version 3? We're up to v5 :)